# Javascript error halts $document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I'm updating an existing website running on Expression Engine. So far, I've stayed away from any code I didn't write or couldn't understand. I recently must have altered some bit of code someplace (helpful, I know) and now a block of JS I didn't write is causing an error that seems to bypass the document.ready() event. The window.load() event however is still taking place.

In the Chrome DevTools Console, the error "Uncought TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of UNDEFINED" points to the definition of a function "fixedEncodeURIComponent" pasted below.

```
$("#MessageContainer.Counted").counter({
type: 'char',
goal: 250,
count: 'down' 
}).change(function(){
var TEMP = fixedEncodeURIComponent($(this).val());
$("#Message").val(TEMP);
});

var TEMP = fixedEncodeURIComponent($("#MessageContainer.Test").val());
$("#Message").val(TEMP);

function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
str=str.replace(/"/g, '');
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, escape);
}
```

As I interpret the error, this function is being passed a variable that is not a string. I added an alert(str) to the function definition and the result was UNDEFINED as I expected. The first of several unknowns for me is which call to the function 'fixedEncodeURIComponent' is being passed a bad variable. I assume that it's the first call, but that's just a guess. It so happens that this first call contains a syntax I have never encountered before. I don't know how to interpret what happens when $(this) is passed as a function argument.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there's more information you need please let me know. The client's site is password protected but I can include any code you request.

Thank you.

Comment: `$(this).val()` is returning undefiend. Most likely `this` isn't a dom node, or the dom node doesn't have a value attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Since I haven't encountered the 'this' keyword passed as a function argument, I'm not sure how to track down the missing DOM node. Any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably, the first call to `fixedEncodeURIComponent` is being called within a function whose `this` context is not a DOM node or other item on which `.val()` can be called (when it looks like it should be). You might have to trace back what calls the function that contains that first call. When you're stopped on a breakpoint in your dev tools, you can look at the call stack to see where things originated, and hopefully find where something is being called incorrectly or returning a "bad" value (i.e. not a DOM node).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the dev tools. When stepping through function calls, the exception is actually being thrown by the second call to fixedEncodeURIComponent. At that point, str is UNDEFINED, even though we're using the jquery selector "#MessageContainer.Test" which is only being loaded into the DOM on one page of the site. This JS is located in an init file that executes at each page load. I don't understand why the live site executing the same JS but does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess that the `});` on line 3 is exiting a document.ready context. If that's the case then your second call to `fixedEncodeURIComponent` may be getting called before the DOM is even loaded.

Start by wrapping

`var TEMP = fixedEncodeURIComponent($("#MessageContainer.Test").val());
$("#Message").val(TEMP);`

in a

`$(function() {

// code

});`

block. If that doesn't work, check that #MessageContainer.Test actually matches an element. Since this is code you inherited, the class name "Test" clues me in that the block in question might be a remnant of someone trying to debug an issue and maybe it should have been removed.

Comment: Good catch. I updated the original question to reflect the lines I had originally omitted. Wrapping the second call to fixedEncodeURIComponent as you suggested did not eliminate the error, but now the rest of the JS is executing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `$("#MessageContainer.Test")` since it looks like its supposed to be an ID selector instead of what it actually is when jQUery parses it(which is an ID selector combined with a class selector).  `$("MessageContainer\\.Test")`  allows you to select an element with ID MessageContainer.Test

Comment: You were right. It was the second call to fixedEncodeURIComponent that's causing the error. I've modified the question with a few lines of code I had originally omitted.